# Unit testing a service with $resource, $httpbackend vs mocking

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-services

When unit testing a service that usings `$resource`, what is best practice - using `$httpBackend` or mocking the resource?

I have the following service:

```
  angular.module('example')
    .factory('MyService', ['$resource',
      function($resource) {

       var service = $resource('/api/example/', {}, {
          create: {
            method: 'POST'
          }
        });

        var create = function(payload) {
          return service.create({}, payload).$promise;
        };

        return {
          create: create
        };
      }
    ]);
```

Using $httpbackend

```
    describe('#create', function() {
      it('should send a post request to api/example', function() {
        $httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/example')
          .respond({
            name: 'Something'
          });

        MyService.create({ example: 'payload' }});

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(MyService.create).toEqual({example: 'payload'})
      });
    });
```

Comment: Use $httpBackend, that is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

When you are testing the service, use `$httpBackend`. It's designed as a stand-in for the usual `$http` module, so you can guarantee your service's call through `$resource` and back does the right thing.

If you were to mock `$resource`, you wouldn't be exercising nearly as much of the code path. You would also be entangling your tests with the implementation of your service, which could conceivably switch from using `$resource` to using `$http` directly, or some third module. Your test doesn't care how the HTTP call is made, just that it's the right one and it returns some expected data.

When you're testing some part of your system other than the service, mock away. In that case, you only need `MyService.create` to return a particular object, and you don't care how it gets it. There's no reason to tie non-service tests to the HTTP call the service needs to make.